# checking returns true when string doesn't even match (RegEx)

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to validate user's phone number format on my site by using JS's regular expression , I use this pattern **XXX**-XXXXXX and (**XXX** represents '022' of  my city), but when I test it by using **XXXX**-XXXXXX format, it's still considered as the same , What is exactly going on here ??

***** when the user type, let say, **0222**-XXXXXX , the method below accept it as a true  , ehh ??!!#@$

```
   var pattern= /\d{3}-\d{6}/; // this is the phone pattern


   // below is method for checking
   function periksaTelp(that) {
        if (pattern.test(that.value)) { 
            document.write("Phone format is accepted !"); 
        }          
        else { 
           document.write("Non valid Phone format !"); 
        }
   }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add start and end pattern to your regex. So it will be like,

```
/^\d{3}-\d{6}$/
```

For validation purposes, it would be better if you add start and end patterns. The above regex means, phone number must have three digits before `-` and 6 digits after `-`.

For example:

If the given phone number is `0222-989898`, then this regex `\d{3}-\d{6}` matches  `222-989898`, so it returns true. But if we put start and end patterns, `^\d{3}-\d{6}$` it tells the regex engine that there must be 3 digits before `-` and 6 digits after `-`. In your case it's four digits before `-`, so it would fail.

Comment: @Fev normally `^` means start of the line. But in the character class `[^]` means negation only if the carrot symbol is at the start of char class.